# How can i store a value as global variable from an API response and pass it to another API as parameter in Cucumber feature file using REST assured

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, rest-assured, cucumber-serenity

I am designing automation scripts on Cucumber BDD framework for REST APIs using Rest assured.
I have one api which generates the "Token" and then there is an another api for order create which requires this "Token" in the authorisation parameter. Here is my feature file

Feature: Create Order API

```
  @Background:
  Scenario Outline: Generate Access token With Valid Details
    Given Query param for request
      | grant_type         |
      | client_credentials |
    Given Basic Auth keys for request "<userName>" and "<key>"
    When Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_GET_AUTH_KEY"
#    And Set global "access_token" in "token"
    And Perform "POST" request using
    Then status code is 200
    And  response contains "scope"
    Examples:
      | userName    | key |                                                                  
   | AWnCbuv9Bee0_6 | EMWowD696LqfznidhQ2RT_jZL2ys |


  Now response of above API is as follows.

{
    "scope": "https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/invoicing https://uri.pppaypal.com/services/applications/webhooks",
    "access_token": "ALs1szFnv2TJ19Zf3vq",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "app_id": "APP-284543T",
    "expires_in": 311286,
    "nonce": "2022-05-31T03:41:41ZWs9dpOQ"
}
```

Now i need this "access_token" as  in the "Create Order API" Authorisation parameter withe Bearer. the "Create Order API" feature file is below.

```
 Scenario: Verify create order api using valid auth
    Given Generate request
    And Build request for baseurl "PAYPAL_BASE_URI" and endpoint "ENDPOINT_CREATE_ORDER_API"
    And Set header values as
      | Content-Type     | Authorization                                                                                            |
      | application/json | Bearer <token> |
    When Perform "POST" request using "FILE_PATH_ORDER_JSON"
    Then status code is 201
```

How can i set "access_token" in "token" as global variable from the feature file so that i can use it anywhere in this feature file using the following step?

```
And Set global "access_token" in "token"
```

Comment: just put it as `public static String TOKEN` to make it a global variable

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 here "TOKEN" is just an example. the logic should work for any attribute fetched from a response and need to assign it to the variable name from feature file itself.

For example:
Set global "access_token" in "token"
OR
Set global "app_id" in "appid"

Comment: You may need `public static` Map, then get value by key. It will apply for other variables

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scenario context object or a test context object (depending on the needed lifetime of the object) in which you can have a HashMap with key-value pairs. You can then use this object to store the information you need and retrieve it later. Take a look at this article, as it explains the concept in great detail: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/share-data-between-steps-in-cucumber-using-scenario-context/